# How to create an app in MS Azure to schedule an appointment in outlook office 365 using aws lex

Tags: azure, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, aws-lex, outlook-calendar

I'm entirely new to MS Azure. I want to make an appointment program using amazon lex which should check free time of the agent and the customer in the outlook office 365 calendar and after confirming the time it should make appointment in both of theirs outlook calendar.
I tried with this [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/schedule-an-appointment-in-office-365-using-an-amazon-lex-bot/) but MS Azure is entirely changed now. 
Anyone knows this please guide me to accomplish the step **Create an Office 365 application**.

Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the steps below:

1. Log in to [Azure Portal app registrations page](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps) with your Azure
   admin account.
2. Click on "**New registration**". Enter the values for **Name**,
   **Supported account types**, **Redirect URI (optional)**. Click on "**register**" button at the bottom.

   [image]

   Record the Application (client) ID on **OverView** page for late
   use.
3. Select the **Certificates & secrets** section. Add a **New client
   secret**. Record the secret (password) for late use. Please note
   this password will be displayed only once.

   [image]
4. Add the **Calendars.ReadWrite** permission in **API permissions**
   section. After adding the permission, click on "**Grant admin
   consent for {your tenant}**" to complete the admin consent process
   (it will require you log in with your Azure admin account).

   [image]

Now you have all the steps completed.

You can get the Azure Active Directory Id from [Azure AD properties page](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties). (See Directory ID)

All the other required information (Application Id, Redirect Uri, Application Password) can be found from the above steps.